# What's the best way / best practice to handle boolean in a Laravel 8 Request class?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, request, laravel-8

I have some standard single checkboxes that define a specific boolean value, i.e. is_active

```
 <label class="form-check-label text-google">
   <input type="checkbox" name="is_active" id="is_active" value="1" class="form-check-input"
      @if (old('is_active') == '1' || (empty(old()) && $doctor->is_active == 1)) checked @endif>
      {{ __('Doctor activated') }}
      <i class="input-helper"></i>
 </label>
```

When sending it to my Controller the request runs through a custom Request class, where I currently do the following. Mainly important for the updating method, so deselected checkbox will be updated in the database.

```
  /**
  * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
  *
  * @return array
  */
  public function rules()
 {
   $this->request->set("is_active", $this->request->has("is_active"));

   return [ ...
```

I also casted the is_active property in the Model as boolean value.
What is best practice here? I couldn't find anything that leads me in the right direction...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not that clear. For what I can see, you have the `is_active` property of the form set to `1`, and then you want to override this value in the Request object before the validation, is this what you are attempting?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to touch the request before the validation, you could make use of this method: [`prepareForValidation()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation):

> #### Prepare Input For Validation
>
> If you need to prepare or sanitize any data from the request before
> you apply your validation rules, you may use the prepareForValidation
> method:
>
> ```
> use Illuminate\Support\Str;
>
> /**
>  * Prepare the data for validation.
>  *
>  * @return void
>  */
> protected function prepareForValidation()
> {
>     $this->merge([
>         'slug' => Str::slug($this->slug),
>     ]);
> }
> ```

So in your case you can do:

```php
public function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'is_active' => $this->request->has('is_active')),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: That's great, that method `prepareForValidation` is what I was looking for... Your side note however does not solve the issue as the checkbox does not send any value when deselected and I need the false of the deselected checkbox

Answer (score 0):

as i read you want to know if there is a value or not, in fact i think you can use the class Request `filled` function.